# Import excel Accounting data to SQL with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis, csv-import

Every week I am receiving a CSV export which contains `Accounting` data. This accounting data has parenthesis to represent negative values and the parenthesis carry over into the CSV.

> How do I import negative `Accounting` values to SQL Server with SSIS?

The options I see are:

1. Request a data type change in the Source file
2. Handle the data conversion within SSIS

> Should I create a function to trim parenthesis from negative values? Is there an SSIS tool which will help convert `accounting` data types into a SQL INT?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure the value in the column is actually (123) to represent -123?  If the datatype in Excel is money and the format is set to () for - it will show with parenthesis but not actually have them in the value of the column.  If any calculations are done on the columns in excel you can bet that the parenthesis are a display format NOT the actual value of the field

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is an SSIS tool, Derived Column Transform. Use the REPLACE function with it, it should get you what you need. Something like this: REPLACE(REPLACE([YourField],'(','-'),')','')